# Homework: C++ reverse string by swapping characters using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have program that will swap all of the characters in strings using pointers. My problem occurs when I try to delete the pointers and deallocate the memory. I get an invalid pointer error, even when I try and delete the pointer right after I create them. This is a computer science course activity that must be done like this, it is not for a grade, I just want to learn from whatever mistake I am making.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    cin >> s;

    char a = 'a';
    char b = 'b';
    char *c1 = &a, *c2 = &b;

    int len = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char temp;

        *c1 = s[i];
        *c2 = s[(len - i) -1];

        cout << "c1 " << *c1 << endl << "c2 " << *c2 << endl;

        temp = *c1;
        *c1 = *c2;
        *c2 = temp;

        if (i == len - 1) {
            cout << "Should be deallocating memory" << endl;
            delete c1, c2;
            cout << "Set to null" << endl;
            c1 = NULL;
            c2 = NULL;
        }
      }

      cout << "s " << s << endl;

      return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());` Why on earth are you trying to delete automatic variables?

Comment: It's was the requirements for a class activity. It's not for a grade, and I don't really even need to do it, I just want to know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

`new` allocates memory, and you haven't done that. Nor should you. Your memory is allocated as part of the `std::string` object, and will be automatically removed when it goes out of scope.

See [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

At this stage, there is probably no need for you to use `new` or `delete`, you should just use the standard classes like `std::string` and `std::vector<T>`. If you ever do, it's likely you should only do so inside a constructor and destructor. There may be rare cases where this doesn't apply, but in those cases you should be very careful not to leak on an exception being calls. This isn't one of those rare cases, indeed it's far from it.